# How often does the omega theorem hold?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Write $\psi(x) = \sum_{n\le x} \Lambda(n)$. The classical omega theorem says that

$\psi(x) - x = \Omega_{\pm}(x^{1/2})$.

Question:  How often does this hold?  For example, what do we know about the size of the set

$\{ n\le x:   \psi(x) - x > c x^{1/2}  \}$

for some $c$? Ditto for $\psi(x) - x < c x^{1/2}$.  What about replacing e.g. $x^{1/2}$ by $x^{\alpha}$ for some fixed $0 < \alpha < 1/2$?  What's a good reference for such results?  Thanks!

Comment: Not to be confused with the [Omega lemma](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01956491)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $c(\varepsilon)>0$ and $X_0(\varepsilon)>0$ such that for any $X>X_0(\varepsilon)$ we have
$$\sup_{X\leq x\leq X^{1+\varepsilon}}\frac{\psi(x)-x}{\sqrt{x}\log\log x}>c(\varepsilon)\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\inf_{X\leq x\leq X^{1+\varepsilon}}\frac{\psi(x)-x}{\sqrt{x}\log\log x}<-c(\varepsilon).$$
More precisely, [Ingham (1935)](https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/1395100) proved a stronger result for the case when the real parts of the zeta zeros have a maximum, while [Pintz (1980)](https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/1393142) proved a stronger result for the case when the real parts of the zeta zeros do not have a maximum. There might be even stronger results in the literature, please check.

Comment: Thanks for the references.  Ingram's paper make reference to a theorem of Bohr on diophantine approximation.  I'm new to this subject; could you give me an English reference of Bohr's result, please?  Thanks!

Comment: @WSao I recommend that you study Bohr's book "Almost periodic functions". Consider $f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^N\max\left(0,1-q\left\|c_n x\right\|\right)$, where $c_n:=\gamma_n/(2\pi)$. This is a sum of continuous periodic functions, hence it is almost periodic (as shown by Bohr). In particular, every sufficiently long interval contains $U$ such that $\sup_x|f(x+U)-f(x)|<1$.
Take such a $U$. From $f(0)=N$ it follows that $f(U)>N-1$, so none of the $N$ terms in the definition of 
$f(x)$ vanishes at $U$. That is, $\|c_n U\|<1/q$ holds for $n\in\{1,\dotsc,N\}$. This is the claim that Ingham uses.